# getter setter Model class Oop

Tags: ios, swift, oop

hello I am new to IOS and oop programming so I want to know what should be the best way or standard way to do this which I am going to describe.

I am declaring a  Model class like this

```
class Trip: NSObject {
    var tripTitle: String
    var tripSummary: String
    var fee: Int
    var departureCountry: String

init(userName: String,tripTitle: String, tripSummary: String,fee: Int, departureCountry: String) {
        self.tripTitle = tripTitle
        self.tripSummary = tripSummary

        self.fee = fee
        self.departureCountry = departureCountry
    } 

    }
```

In controller classes I  first set the values of these variables and then  get the values which are being set from the class object. Now I have a situation in which I want to set only a few variables of these class not all. so whenever I want to set few variables I have to send the null values in the parameters of the class object. So I want to know how can I define my own constructor or if I can do this without constructor as well. 
I did some research on google and I come across to know about`computed properties` `getter setter`. But it says that we can only used these when there are chances you want to return the result with some modification. so I want to know what would be the best method or standard approach to accomplish this

Comment: You can have more than one initializer method in the class. This means that in your new initializer you may pass only the parameters that are != null. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203) are some useful info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by providing default values in the `init` method

```
class Trip: NSObject {
  var userName: String
  var tripTitle: String
  var tripSummary: String
  var fee: Int
  var departureCountry: String

  init(userName: String = "", tripTitle: String = "" , tripSummary: String = "" , fee: Int = 0, departureCountry: String = "USA") {
    self.userName = userName
    self.tripTitle = tripTitle
    self.tripSummary = tripSummary
    self.fee = fee
    self.departureCountry = departureCountry
  }
}
```

Now you can call the initializer this way

```
let trip = Trip(userName:"John", fee: 12)
```

`userName` is set to John, `fee` is set to 12, all other properties are set to the default values

---

Or you assign the default values in the declaration lines, then you don't even need an initializer

```
class Trip: NSObject {
  var userName = ""
  var tripTitle = ""
  var tripSummary = ""
  var fee = 0
  var departureCountry = "USA"
}


let trip = Trip()
trip.userName = "John"
trip.fee = 12
```

You can do the same with optionals.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am confused wether should I go with this approach or should I go with multiple constructors option. what do you recommend ? btw how do you assign UIImage type variable nil here ? I can't seem to figure it out by using your method

Comment: Just add an optional property `var tripImage : UIImage?`. It has an implicit default value of `nil`. You can mix optional and non-optional types. Use the syntax which suits your design best.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but according to my interpretation of your problem, you are looking to initiate a class sometimes with some parameters, and sometimes with others.

If you have a lot of situations where you want to input two or three different parameters but not the rest, you can add additional init() functions to your "Trip" class.

For example, if you know that sometimes you will only have a userName and tripTitle parameter to pass to the class, you could create another init() function as shown below:

```
class Trip: NSObject {
var tripTitle: String
var tripSummary: String?
var fee: Int?
var departureCountry: String?

init(userName: String,tripTitle: String, tripSummary: String,fee: Int, departureCountry: String) {
    self.tripTitle = tripTitle
    self.tripSummary = tripSummary

    self.fee = fee
    self.departureCountry = departureCountry
}

init(userName: String,tripTitle: String){
    self.tripTitle = tripTitle
}
```

Note that in order to do this safely, you would have to mark tripSummary, fee, and departureCountry as optionals when initiated.

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1

Use a `struct` and throw away the `NSObject` part, **unless** there is a good reason for using a `class` like:

- you want `Objective-C` compatibility
- you want multiple parts of your program to manipulate the same object
- you want to use inheritance

### Step 2

Declare your properties as constants `let` unless you need to change them after the Trip value has been created.

### Step 3

Declare as `optionals` the properties that could be `nil`

### Step 4

Define a single initializer and add default `nil values` to the parameters that could be `nil`. This will allow you to use every combination of the param with default value when creating the value (look at my sample below).

### Result

```
struct Trip {
    let tripTitle: String
    let tripSummary: String?
    let fee: Int?
    let departureCountry: String?

    init(tripTitle: String, tripSummary:String?=nil, fee:Int?=nil, departureCountry:String?=nil) {
        self.tripTitle = tripTitle
        self.tripSummary = tripSummary
        self.fee = fee
        self.departureCountry = departureCountry
    } 
}
```

### Usage

```
let rome = Trip(tripTitle: "Rome")
let london = Trip(tripTitle: "London", tripSummary: "A nice holiday")
let berlin = Trip(tripTitle: "Berlin", fee: 100)
let madrid = Trip(tripTitle: "Madrid", departureCountry: "Italy")
```